# file_get_contents does not seem to work after PHP 8.0 update

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-8

I have no idea if this is related to a newly update on my web servers to PHP 8.0 from 7.4, but this seems to have happened after the update.

I am retrieving JSON (and decoding it) from another URL. But after the update the `file_get_contents` returns nothing - its empty.

This is what I have tried to locate the problem:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/json.php"); // not actual link
echo $json . "<br>";

$dataArray = json_decode($json);
echo var_dump($dataArray);
```

The first echo is just blank and the second echo is `NULL`.

What could be wrong here? This is at the TOP of the page, so no code is prior to this.

**EDIT**
I added the code to get errors and this is the start of what I got:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/json.php): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
```

**EDIT 2**

The suggested solution is that I add the `$ctx`variable to file_get_contents, but I still get the same error.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(['http' => ['protocol_version' => '1.0']]);
echo file_get_contents('https://LINKHERE.com', false, $ctx);
```

Comment: Have a go using curl instead

Comment: If you bring the link up in a browser does it display anything? Did you check the web server error log? add this to see the errors in the browser. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @JasonK I have made and edit to show the error I got. Yes, the link shows what it should when I visit it in a browser :)

Comment: The error indicates that PHP is sending the request, but the server is rejecting it. Possibly this is because of the change to advertise HTTP 1.1 in PHP 8.0 - search for "HTTP/1.1" on [this PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) for details and some suggested code which would help in that case.

Comment: Although, looking at [the definition of status 406](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) that doesn't seem likely. More likely the change in PHP version is coincidence, and something has changed at the remote end.

Comment: @IMSoP searched and found a solution, but see the second edit, it unfortunately did not work :(

Comment: @M.Holm Yeah, it was just a guess, because you mentioned the PHP 8.0 upgrade. By the way, the domain "example.com" is specially reserved for examples, which is why I keep editing it into the question instead of URLs which might accidentally lead somewhere dodgy.

Comment: @IMSoP what does that mean? Could you ELI5? The json webpage is also mine, just another domain. Sorry about the example url, that's cool I'll do that in the future! Thanks!

Comment: @M.Holm Sorry, which comment did you want more explanation for?

Comment: @IMSoP this one "More likely the change in PHP version is coincidence, and something has changed at the remote end.". I do not understand what to do here :)

Comment: @M.Holm PHP is sending a request to some URL. The web server serving that URL is looking at the request, and deciding that it is "Not Acceptable". [This page documenting the status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) suggests that the server might be expecting a particular `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding` or `Accept-Language` header. If you're in control of the other URL, you'll need to do some debugging there - is there some PHP code for producing the JSON, maybe using a PHP framework that makes use of those headers?

Comment: @IMSoP all the other URL is doing, is displaying an array in json, like this ["something1", "something2", "something3"], where the data is fetching from it's own database. It is just so I can use data from the "json" domain to the file_get_contents domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use cURL instead of `file_get_contents`as the HTTP/1.1 somehow made the use of `file_get_contents` impossible. Thank you to all of you who used time to help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because it generates a php error and your error reporting is not turned on.

For the first line I got an error after I tested it:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/json.php): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in /home/genie/fileget.php on line 2
```

But if I turn off error reporting I got the same what you described.

You should check your error reporting settings and turn on error reporting and display errors.

And reason why you got for the first json nothing is because it's value is false. If you var_dump it you got a false because the page what you would like to include has a 404 header.

By default file_get_contents only returns the content of HTTP 200 responses.

Comment: Hi András. Thank you for taking the time to look into my problem. The link I've used, is just and example. It is not real, therefore you get a 404. When I use my actual link, I get a 406 error.

Comment: yes but it is the same, because file_get_contents only returns if you get http 200. If you get 406 it is the same, you will get an error into your log.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your **PHP.ini** that is active the flag: `fopen_url` or `allow_url_fopen`.

If you have an hosting, go to the hosting settings and try to edit the PHP.ini or ask for assistance.

In my case, was the flag disabled after upgrading to PHP 8.